Setting a print area with VBA in a PivotTable
I'm trying to find my last row in a PivotTable which can be filtered and hence changes in row size.
The below code does not find the last row.
However, the code works if I manually set the lastRow = 9.
  ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:AN9").Address

Hence I assume that this line is not working properly:
  lastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Sub SetPrintArea()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RELATION LEVEL")

  ' find the last row with formatting, to be included in print range
  lastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

  ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:AN" & lastRow).Address
End Sub

What am I doing wrong to set up the printing area?

FYI: I tried using the code as described here: Set printing area In Excel 2013 using macro
I expect to get the last row and set up the printing area from A1 to AN X.
The print area is not set up correctly however.

Pivot tables have various ranges which are accessible via VBA: https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/   You can pick the most-relevant one and get the row number of its last row.

You can also try: LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row changing "A" with whatever column has the last row of the pivot table and no other data underneath it.  or you can use the used range: LastRow = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

I used this one: LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Essentially I knew which column to take, so the former seemed like the better solution in my case.
